# AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
#models.py file

from django.db import models


class Stocks(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)



class DataChoice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I have changed models file and added "text" inside "Stocks". I ran makemigrations command and then migrate command but when I run migrate command I got an error, don't know why.

This is full error traceback:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, stocks, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying stocks.0002_auto_20150226_1624...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 167, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 74, in _remake_table
self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 171, in effective_default
default = field.get_default()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 720, in get_default
return force_text(self.default, strings_only=True)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 85, in force_text
s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __str__
model = self.model
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

migrations file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('stocks', '0005_auto_20150226_1714'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stocks',
            name='text',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=50),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please show the *full* error traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added now, please check it.

Comment: Could you post your migration file? The error is likely going to be in there

Comment: @awwester You mean initial file inside migrations folder, right?

Comment: yes, whichever migration files are being ran (it could be more than just the init)

Comment: There are total 7 files other than initial and the reason I think is  because I have once added then removed and done this two-three times.

Comment: @awwester I have added migrations file, take a look.

Comment: @MukeshThawani hmm nothing in that one that stands out, might take a look through the dependency migrations and see if you see something strange such as `CharField.model`

Comment: No, there is nothing in dependency like     CharField.model,
I have checked that already.

Comment: there will be a migrations folder inside your `app folder` delete it then try, else there will also be a `migration table` in your database if your delete migrations history, delete the records if you are in development stages, else be aware if it is on production.

Comment: The migration file you provided above is `stocks.0002_auto_20150226_1624` ? It strangely seems to depend on a future migration in same app: `('stocks', '0005_auto_20150226_1714')` .. can you please clarify your migration structure, what was the field name before and what else was changed?

Answer (score 0):

May be adding a default value or **null=True**, may solve this issue.